# VBA search specific user in Outlook GAL

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, gal

I want to search a specific user (e.g. Clinton, Bill) in the GAL and get all the information like e-mail address, phone, street etc. in Excel.

How do I do that in VBA?

Answer (score 1):

Call `Application.Session.CreateRecipient` passing the name as a string, then call `Recipient.Resolve` on the returned `Recipient` object. Use the `Recipient.AddressEntry` property (e.g. you can call `AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser`).